# Fractional vs. integer solution of a maximal matching

Tags: integer-programming

If we know that it takes at least $t$ steps to compute a fractional maximal matching, does it then also take at least $t$ steps to compute a integer maximal matching?

Comment: Context, please.  What do you mean by a fractional maximal matching?  Is an integer maximal matching a special case of a fractional maximal matching?

Comment: I'm sorry! Consider a graph $G=(V,E)$. A fractional maximal matching is an assignment of values $x_e \in [0,1]$ to edges $e \in E$ such that for ell edges $e = \{u,v\} \in E$ we either have $\sum_{e \in E \colon u \in e} x_e =1$ or $\sum_{e\in E \colon v \in e} x_e = 1$ (maximality) and for all $v  \in V$ we have $\sum_{e \in E \colon v \in e} x_e \leq 1$. 

An integer maximal matching is an assignment $x_e \in \{0,1\}$ such that for every vertex $v \in V$ we have $\sum_{e\in E \colon v \in e} x_e\leq 1$.

Comment: Presumably you want the maximality condition for the integer case as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that "it takes at least $t$ steps to ..." means "every algorithm 
to ... takes at least $t$ steps".

By  definition, an integer maximal matching is a fractional maximal matching, and there is always an integer maximal matching.  Thus every algorithm for  integer maximal matching is an algorithm for fractional maximal matching, so the statement is true.

On the other hand, if you had in mind a particular algorithm (call it A) for fractional maximal matching and a different algorithm (B) for integer maximal matching, it is quite possible that A takes more steps than B for some instances.